EOFError: EOF when reading a line in cpanel
I wrote a program in python that downloads stories of my following in instagram, but when I put  this project in my host it just opens the web and when I enter the username and password it doesn't download stories and says this

error:EOFError: EOF when reading a line ''

in cpanel
This is my python code:
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, send_file  
from instagrapi import Client  
import os  
import shutil  
import zipfile  

app = Flask(__name__)  

# Ensure the download directory exists  
DOWNLOAD_DIR = "downloads"  
if not os.path.exists(DOWNLOAD_DIR):  
    os.makedirs(DOWNLOAD_DIR)  

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])  
def home():  
    return render_template('index.html')
@app.route('/download', methods=['POST'])  
def download_stories():  
    username = request.form['username']  
    password = request.form['password']  
    
    cl = Client()  
    cl.login(username, password)  

    following_users = cl.user_following(cl.user_id)  

    # Create a directory for the user stories  
    user_stories_dir = os.path.join(DOWNLOAD_DIR, username)  
    if not os.path.exists(user_stories_dir):  
        os.makedirs(user_stories_dir)  

    # Loop through each user the logged-in user is following  
    for user in following_users:  
        user_id = user  
        user_info = cl.user_info(user_id)  
        followed_username = user_info.username  

        # Download stories for the current user  
        stories = cl.user_stories(user_id)  
        
        for story in stories:  
            story_url = story.video_url or story.thumbnail_url  
            file_extension = ".jpg" if story.thumbnail_url else ".mp4"  
            filename = os.path.join(user_stories_dir, f"{followed_username}_{story.pk}{file_extension}")  
            story_content = cl.story_download(story.pk)  
            
            if isinstance(story_content, str) or isinstance(story_content, bytes):  
                with open(filename, "wb") as f:  
                    f.write(story_content)  
            elif hasattr(story_content, 'name'):  
                shutil.move(story_content, filename)  

    # Create a zip file of the downloaded stories  
    zip_filename = os.path.join(DOWNLOAD_DIR, f"{username}_stories.zip")  
    with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_filename, 'w') as zipf:  
        for root, _, files in os.walk(user_stories_dir):  
            for file in files:  
                zipf.write(os.path.join(root, file), file)  

    return send_file(zip_filename, as_attachment=True)  

@app.route('/downloads/<path:filename>', methods=['GET'])
def download_file(filename):  
    return send_file(os.path.join(DOWNLOAD_DIR, filename), as_attachment=True)  

if __name__ == '__main__':  
    app.run(debug=True)


Please edit the question to include the full stack trace. Also, identify the line of code in your excerpt where this exception occurs. Once that is known, it's likely that you can simplify your code excerpt by removing some code that doesn't get reached.
